# flow of scraping a site

Tags: php, web-scraping, simple-html-dom

I want to scrape base on users' input but unlucky the site doesn't have good built-in search function. The webmaster of the site use google custom search to replace its default search function. The results are flawless, like user search shoe Kobe 2014, the google custom search will able to give the correct page, then I can scrape the page.

However, on scraping from the search engine result, it has many limitation, like Google's API has to pay if u more request, same goes to Bing API.

Comment: for the one who voted down, show up and give ur solution.

Comment: That's not how it works here. My answer is a good one. You could contact the site's owner and discuss your problem with them. If they think you offer added value they might be willing to help you.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware u r kidding me, web scrapping require a talk to site owner is not web scrapping anymore..

Comment: Well, that just shows your intentions doesn't it?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware web scrapping isn't a crime, it's technique!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried contacting the site's owner? Afterall it's their information you're using.